# Nested tabularx breaks when I increase the width from .7\textwidth to .8\textwidth

Tags: tabularx

I am trying to create a nested table with three levels. I got it to look like how I want it to when I set the width of the outermost table to be anything less than .7\textwidth. However, I wanted to scale it up so it took up the entire page. When I change this to \textwidth or even .8\textwidth or .9\textwidth, it seems like the columns ate becoming extremely narrow. And I am not quite sure what is happening!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, margin = .5]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\small\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{A}{>{\hsize=.80\hsize}Y}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\hsize=.35\hsize}Y}

\begin{document}


\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{.72\textwidth}{|Z|Y|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Analysis} & \textbf{Factors} \\

    \hline
    &   \\

    \textbf{Gender Generic Referents}
    & {\begin{tabularx}{.5\textwidth}{|A|Y|Y|}
            \cline{1-3}
            & \textbf{Binary} & \textbf{Non-binary}\\ \cline{1-3}

            \textbf{Ambig} & she-he & she-he\\ \cline{1-3}
            \textbf{Unambig} & incongruent-congruent & incongruent-congruent\\ \cline{1-3}          
    \end{tabularx}} \\
    & \\
    \hline

    &   \\
    \textbf{Gender Specific Referents}
    & {\begin{tabularx}{.5\textwidth}{|A|Y|Y|}
            \cline{1-3}
            & \textbf{Binary} & \textbf{Non-binary}\\ \cline{1-3}

            \textbf{Ambig} & she-he & she-he\\ \cline{1-3}
            \textbf{Unambig} & incongruent-congruent & incongruent-congruent\\ \cline{1-3}          
    \end{tabularx}} \\
    & \\
    \hline


    &   \\
    \textbf{Number Specific Referents}
    & {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|A|Y|Y|}
            \cline{1-3}
            & \textbf{Binary} & \textbf{Non-binary}\\ \cline{1-3}

            \textbf{Ambig} 
            & &\\
            & {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Y|Y|}
                    \cline{1-2}
                    Sing & Plur \\ \cline{1-2}
            \end{tabularx}}  

            & {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Y|Y|}
                    \cline{1-2}
                    Sing & Plur \\ \cline{1-2}
            \end{tabularx}} \\


            & {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Y|Y|}
                    \cline{1-2}
                    Sing & Plur \\ \cline{1-2}
            \end{tabularx}}

            & {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Y|Y|}
                    \cline{1-2}
                    Sing & Plur \\ \cline{1-2}
            \end{tabularx}}\\ \cline{1-3}




            \textbf{Unambig} 
            & &\\
            & {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Y|Y|}
                    \cline{1-2}
                    Sing & Plur \\ \cline{1-2}
            \end{tabularx}}  

            & {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Y|Y|}
                    \cline{1-2}
                    Sing & Plur \\ \cline{1-2}
            \end{tabularx}} \\


            & {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Y|Y|}
                    \cline{1-2}
                    Sing & Plur \\ \cline{1-2}
            \end{tabularx}}

            & {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Y|Y|}
                    \cline{1-2}
                    Sing & Plur \\ \cline{1-2}
            \end{tabularx}}\\ \cline{1-3}


    \end{tabularx}} \\
    & \\
    \hline

    & \\
    \textbf{Number Generic Referents}
    & {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|A|Y|Y|}
            \cline{1-3}
            & \textbf{Binary} & \textbf{Non-binary}\\ \cline{1-3}

            \textbf{Ambig} 
            & &\\
            & {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Y|Y|}
                    \cline{1-2}
                    Sing & Plur \\ \cline{1-2}
            \end{tabularx}}  

            & {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Y|Y|}
                    \cline{1-2}
                    Sing & Plur \\ \cline{1-2}
            \end{tabularx}} \\


            & {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Y|Y|}
                    \cline{1-2}
                    Sing & Plur \\ \cline{1-2}
            \end{tabularx}}

            & {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Y|Y|}
                    \cline{1-2}
                    Sing & Plur \\ \cline{1-2}
            \end{tabularx}}\\ \cline{1-3}




            \textbf{Unambig} 
            & &\\
            & {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Y|Y|}
                    \cline{1-2}
                    Sing & Plur \\ \cline{1-2}
            \end{tabularx}}  

            & {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Y|Y|}
                    \cline{1-2}
                    Sing & Plur \\ \cline{1-2}
            \end{tabularx}} \\


            & {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Y|Y|}
                    \cline{1-2}
                    Sing & Plur \\ \cline{1-2}
            \end{tabularx}}

            & {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Y|Y|}
                    \cline{1-2}
                    Sing & Plur \\ \cline{1-2}
            \end{tabularx}}\\ \cline{1-3}


    \end{tabularx}} \\
    & \\
    \hline

\end{tabularx}
\caption{Analysis Summary (Construal 1)}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image: This is the table I am trying to create]

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. But beside this: nested tabularx can only give you a lot of headaches. Are you sure that you need it?

Comment: The specification is contradictory so the package (and especially the package author:-) can't be blamed for anything bad that happens.  The outer table is incorrect as it has two X columns (ZY) but the total `\hsize` isn't correct (it should be unchanged so the same as 2\hsize) then even though the column widths are being dynamically calculated the cell content is a fixed width .5\textwidth} so can not fit the cells.

Comment: Ulrike - Oops, just fixed it to add \begin{document} and \end{document - it should compile now.  David - I am not sure I follow :( (Sorry I am very new to LaTex)

Comment: I also just edited it to add an image of what I want the table to look like. Is there a better way of doing this that does not involve nested tabularx and editing the \hsize ?

Comment: You can ping somebody like this: @DavidCarlisle to get the attention of the entirely blameless package author, for example. You have `0.8` plus `0.35` of `\hsize` with 2 `X` type columns. But your fractions must be equivalent to an integer equal to the number of `X` type columns i.e. `2` in this case. So you'd need, say, `0.8` and `1.2` or `1.65` and `0.35` or whatever. But then you stick a box of `.5\textwidth` in one of those columns anyway and that content can't be resized to fit - it is just a box with another `tabularx` inside it, of specified total width. So there is no flexibility.

Comment: @cfr Aah I see! I tried two variations to try and not have this contradiction. First, instead of having Z and Y, I tried just having Y and Y. . Second, I replaced the .5\textwidth with \linewidth thinking that this would then make it flexible. But the same problem persisted where the column sizes become extremely small (I further edited the question again to add this image!) Am I misunderstanding  the problem?

Comment: It makes no sense to nest a `tabularx` inside a `tabularx` `X` column. The only way it could possible make sense would be to have the nested one in a standard column e.g. `c` or something and have some other column(s) be `X` type.

Comment: Your outer `tabularx` can't work, even ignoring the rest of the nested stuff, because you have `0.8+0.35=2` which it isn't no-wise-no-how. The nesting just creates further chaos, but the seeds of chaos are there from the very beginning.

Comment: Sorry if this is a very obvious question, but why does it not make sense to nest a tabularx in an X column? If I nested it within a 'c' column, then how would I get it to control the width? Do you recommend I use another way to get the desired output?

Comment: You can nest tabularx but it makes no sense to use a specified width of `.5\textwidth` as then the inner table will be half the page width whatever happens and all the column calculation for the outer table is pointless as whatever width it calculates for the column will be ignored and a block of .5\textwidth will be forced into the space. But in this case the calculation of the column widths for the outer table is anyway broken because of the inserted `\hsize` changes.

Answer (score 3):

The `tabularx` usage has two errors. the main one is that

```
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\small\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\hsize=.35\hsize}Y}

\begin{tabularx}{.72\textwidth}{|Z|Y|}
```

completely breaks the `tabularx` column width calculation as `tabularx` will calculate the column widths necessary to achieve a total width of .72\textwidth, but then you adjust one of the columns  and make it only 35% as wide as calculated, so the algorithm will never manage to achieve the specified total width.

Then the second error is with the nested tables. The outer `tabularx` (even if fixed to address the above issue) is dynamically calculating column widths, but the actual column content is  `\begin{tabularx}{.5\textwidth}` so is always half the page width whatever the calculated width of the outer table column.

`tabularx` is all about adjusting the specified width for line breaking within columns, and you have  almost no linebreaking here at all, you can far more simply just use `tabular`. Some would suggest using less vertical and horizontal rules, but here I have mostly left them in, and just showing the results of using `tabular` rather than `tabularx`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}%margin = .5
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash
 \renewcommand\arraystretch{1}}m{2.45cm}}

\begin{document}


\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}

\begin{table}
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}|l|l|@{}}
    \hline
    \textbf{Analysis} & \textbf{Factors} \\

    \hline

    \textbf{Gender Generic Referents}
    & 
 \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.7}
      \begin{tabular}{@{}l|P|P@{}}
            & \textbf{Binary} & \textbf{Non-binary}\\ \hline

            \textbf{Ambig} & she-he & she-he\\ \hline
            \textbf{Unambig} & incongruent-congruent & incongruent-congruent\\
    \end{tabular} \\
    \hline

    \textbf{Gender Specific Referents}
    &
     \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.7}
      \begin{tabular}{@{}l|P|P@{}}
            & \textbf{Binary} & \textbf{Non-binary}\\ \hline

            \textbf{Ambig} & she-he & she-he\\ \hline
            \textbf{Unambig} & incongruent-congruent & incongruent-congruent\\
    \end{tabular} \\
    \hline


    \textbf{Number Specific Referents}
    &  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.7}
          \begin{tabular}{@{}l|P|P@{}}
            & \textbf{Binary} & \textbf{Non-binary}\\ \hline

            \textbf{Ambig} 
            & \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
                   \hline
                    Sing & Plur \\\hline
            \end{tabular}  

            \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
                   \hline
                    Sing & Plur \\\hline
            \end{tabular}
            &\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
                   \hline
                    Sing & Plur \\\hline
            \end{tabular}

             \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
                   \hline
                    Sing & Plur \\\hline
            \end{tabular}\\\hline
            \textbf{Unambig} 
            & \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
                   \hline
                    Sing & Plur \\\hline
            \end{tabular} 

            \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
                               \hline
                    Sing & Plur \\\hline
           \end{tabular}
&
            \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}

                   \hline
                    Sing & Plur \\\hline
           \end{tabular}

            \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
                   \hline
                    Sing & Plur \\\hline
           \end{tabular}
   \end{tabular} \\
    \hline

    \textbf{Number Generic Referents}
    & \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.7}
              \begin{tabular}{@{}l|P|P@{}}
            & \textbf{Binary} & \textbf{Non-binary}\\ \hline

            \textbf{Ambig} 
            &
                   \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
                   \hline
                    Sing & Plur \\\hline
           \end{tabular}  

            \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
                   \hline
                    Sing & Plur \\\hline
           \end{tabular} &


            \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
                   \hline
                    Sing & Plur \\\hline
           \end{tabular}

            \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
                   \hline
                    Sing & Plur \\\hline
           \end{tabular}\\

\hline
            \textbf{Unambig} 
            & \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
                   \hline
                    Sing & Plur \\\hline
           \end{tabular}  

            \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
                   \hline
                    Sing & Plur \\\hline
           \end{tabular}
            &\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
                   \hline
                    Sing & Plur \\\hline
           \end{tabular}

            \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
                   \hline
                    Sing & Plur \\\hline
           \end{tabular}
   \end{tabular} \\
    \hline

\end{tabular}
\caption{Analysis Summary (Construal 1)}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```